# Javascript - Red outline on textarea that is missing input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to know how to add a red outline around textarea's that have no input
(checking for empty input, then if it is empty, highlight the textarea)

Here is my code:

```
//NEED TO CHANGE THE LINE BELOW SO IT WONT SHOW TEXT, JUST CHANGE BORDER COLOUR
$('#input-area textarea').fadeIn().html('Please enter some instructions.');
```

How can I change this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just chain a css property to the below:

However from your question it's not quite clear if that's what you mean.

```
$('#input-area textarea').fadeIn().html('').css("border","1px solid red");
```

Comment: Since the op doesn't want to show text, I'd make it `.html('')`

Comment: That will leave the red border there even when it is not empty

Comment: that depends on the rest of the code, you can't make that assumption based on the this one line of code..

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick, adding an event listener for change and then seeing if it is empty or not

```
$('#input-area textarea').fadeIn().html('').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val()=='') {
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
    } else {
        $(this).css("border","none");
    }
});
```

Comment: change doesn't work on a textarea in the way you are picturing it here